# Makefile error trying to use a template to compile multiple programs with similar steps

Tags: makefile

I am trying to create a makefile that can compile multiple programs. It has a list of programs and will compile each one separately. Every program has pretty much exactly the same template so I tried this solution:

```
CFLAGS=-O3 -std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror

programs=echo cat yes true false cp

all: $(programs)

$(programs): src/$@.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    $(RM) $(programs)

install: all
    $(CP) $(programs) /usr/local/bin/
```

For some reason, this doesn't work. I get the error

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'src/.c', needed by 'echo'.  Stop.
```

I'm trying to make this portable so no GNU extensions. POSIX Make if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
$(programs): src/$@.c
    ...
```

You can't use [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) like `$@` in the prerequisite list that way. The rule gets expanded before a target has been specified, so the variable contains nothing. (You *can* use it this way but it's a headache.)

Use a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) instead:

```
$(programs): %: src/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```